# How can I set ion-modals height to be equal to its content

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-vue

I have a modal which should have height based on its content, since content could differ from modal to modal. Modal is shown from bottom of the page and is not full screen.

How can I achieve modal behaviour where modals height is equal to its content. Currently whenever modal is opened I calculate height of modals content and then set modals height to it, but this is very bad IMO since it does this on every modal open. If I set height to something like auto or content-fit it is not shown at all. There must be easier way to do this.